# Find the size of a string pointed by a pointer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char *ptr = "stackoverflow"

}
```

Is there any way to find the length of stackoverflow pointed by ptr, as sizeof ptr always gives 4

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. `sizeof()` returns the size required by the type. Since the type you pass to sizeof in this case is a pointer, it will return size of the pointer.

   If you need the size of the data pointed by a pointer you will have to remember it by [**storing it explicitly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string/9631091#9631091).
2. `sizeof()` works at compile time. so, `sizeof(ptr)` will `return 4 or 8 bytes` typically. Instead use `strlen`.

Comment: How to return the size of the string tho ?

Answer (score 59):

Use [strlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) to find the length of (number of characters in) a string

```
const char *ptr = "stackoverflow";
size_t length = strlen(ptr);
```

Another minor point, note that `ptr` is a string literal (a pointer to const memory which cannot be modified).  Its better practice to declare it as const to show this.

Comment: +1 for two good practices, assigning string literals to `const char *` and use of `size_t`

Comment: Indeed - just be careful that if the target is not a null terminated string, this  will measure until it either randomly finds a null in memory, or triggers a memory protection fault in the course of that search.   And of course (as others have pointed out) the returned value does not include the size of the terminating null.

Comment: size_t strLen = strlen(palavra);
  printf("Size of String >> %zu", strLen); For some reason mine shows lenght 0

Answer (score 7):

The [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) function provided by `string.h` gives you how many "real characters" the string pointed by the argument contains. However, this length does not include the terminating null character `'\0'`; you have to consider it if you need the length to allocate memory.

That 4 bytes is the size of a pointer to char on your platform.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int mystrlen(char *);
    char str[100];
    char *p;
    p=str;
    printf("Enter the string..?\n");
    scanf("%s",p);
    int x=mystrlen(p);
    printf("Length of string is=%d\n",x);


}
int mystrlen(char *p)
{
    int c=0;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        c++;
        *p++;
    }
    return(c);
}
```

**simple code to understand**

Comment: This if by far the best answer rather than just pointing out a built in method.

Comment: You can just use *p instead of *p!='\0' in while loop.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but what would happen if `p` pointed to a character and not a string literal? I tested this with the standard `strlen` function, and it seems to return nonsense.

Comment: why use '*p++', p++ would do right ? since p is the pointer reference and *p is the first char pointed. *p++ still works but you are making a value reference that isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
char *ptr = "stackoverflow"
size_t len = strlen(ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

if ptr length is an argument of a function it's reasonable to use pointers as a strings. we can get string length by following code:

```
char *ptr = "stackoverflow";
length=strlen((const char *)ptr);
```

And for more explanation, if string is an input string by user with variable length, we can use following code:

```
unsigned char *ptr;
ptr=(unsigned char *)calloc(50, sizeof(unsigned char));
scanf("%s",ptr );
length=strlen((const char *)ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Purely using pointers you can use pointer arithmetic:

```
int strLen(char *s)
{
    int *p = s;
    while(*p !=’\0’)
    {
        p++;  /* increase the address until the end */
    }
    Return p – s; /* Subtract the two addresses, end - start */
}
```

Comment: Would this not only apply to null-terminated strings? I suppose if you knew that was all you were working with, this could be used...

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a generic C question, it gets pretty high hits when looking this question up for C++. Not only was I in C/C++ territory, I also had to be mindful of Microsoft's [Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) Banned Function Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx) for a specific project which made `strlen` a no-go due to,

> *For critical applications, such as those accepting anonymous Internet connections,* `strlen` *must also be replaced*...

Anyway, this answer is basically just a twist on the answers from the others but with approved Microsoft C++ alternative function calls and considerations for wide-character handling in respect to [C99's updated limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351964/3543437) of 65,535 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int wmain()
{
    //  1 byte per char, 65535 byte limit per C99 updated standard
    //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351964/3543437
    const size_t ASCII_ARRAY_SAFE_SIZE_LIMIT = 65535; 

    //  Theoretical UTF-8 upper byte limit of 6; can typically use 16383 for 4 bytes per char instead:
    //  https://stijndewitt.com/2014/08/09/max-bytes-in-a-utf-8-char/
    const size_t UNICODE_ARRAY_SAFE_SIZE_LIMIT = 10922;

    char ascii_array[] = "ACSCII stuff like ABCD1234.";
    wchar_t unicode_array[] = L"Unicode stuff like → ∞ ∑ Σὲ γνωρίζω τὴν ደሀ ᚦᚫᛏ.";

    char * ascii_array_ptr = &ascii_array[0];
    wchar_t * unicode_array_ptr = &unicode_array[0];

    std::cout << "The string length of the char array is: " << strnlen_s(ascii_array_ptr, ASCII_ARRAY_SAFE_SIZE_LIMIT) << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"The string length of the wchar_t array is: " << wcsnlen_s(unicode_array_ptr, UNICODE_ARRAY_SAFE_SIZE_LIMIT) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The string length of the char array is: 27
The string length of the wchar_t array is: 47
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` gives you the exact length of the string [excluding '\0']

`sizeof()` gives you the size of the data type used.

```
// stackoverflow = 13 Characters
const char* ptr = "stackoverflow";

strlen(ptr);             // 13 bytes - exact size (NOT includes '\0')
sizeof(ptr);             // 4  bytes - Size of integer pointer used by the platform
sizeof(*ptr);            // 1  byte  - Size of char data type

strlen("stackoverflow"); // 13 bytes - exact size
sizeof("stackoverflow"); // 14 bytes - includes '\0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
char *pt = "String of pointer";
int i = 0;
while (*pt != '\0') {
    i++;
    pt++;
}
printf("Length of String : %d", i);
return 0;
}
```

We can also use `strlen()` function or `sizeof()` operator which is builtin in C.
We can also take help of pointer arithmetic as above example.

Comment: In this case, `sizeof()` will evaluate to the size of a pointer, not the length of the string. Did you read the other answers before posting a redundant and inaccurate one?