# C++ DLL to Delphi: How to pass a pointer to data from C++ DLL to Delphi program?

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I want to store data in a DLL and pass its reference and size to the Delphi program.

I created a C++ DLL project and a Delphi application project. Then I load the DLL explicitly by `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

However, I couldn't access the data using the returned reference.

Following are the source codes:

C++ DLL callee function:

```cpp
void __stdcall exportClass::getDataReference(char* data, int* bufferLength)
{   
    // char* charArray: is member of exportClass
    charArray = "Pass this Array of Char By Reference";
    data = charArray;
    bufferLength = sizeof(charArray) / sizeof(charArray[0]);
}
```

Delphi caller:

```pascal
procedure callDllFunction();
var
  dynamicCharArray : array of AnsiChar;
  pData: PAnsiChar;
  length: Integer;
  pInt: ^Integer;
begin
  pData := @dynamicCharArray[0];
  length := 10;
  pInt := @length;
  explicitDllLoaderClass.callGetDataReference(pData, pInt);
  SetLength(dynamicCharArray, length);
end;
```

Comment: There are a lot of details missing. We can't see how you declared the imported function. And we can't see how the imported function is declared. But it's a mistake to export an instance method. The code that sets the length actually assigns to a pointer. I doubt it compiles. The array is allocated after the function has been called. The function can't return anything anyway because it simply assigns to the pointer rather than copying to a buffer. The C++ code won't even work in C++. My advice is to start to getting the code to work just in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous mistakes in this code.

On the C++ side;

- The `data` parameter is being passed *by value*, so reassigning its value will only be local to the function and won't affect the caller at all. You need to pass the parameter by reference/pointer instead. You are attempting to do that with the `bufferLength` parameter, but you are not assigning a value to it correctly.
- using `sizeof()` on a `char*` will not get you the correct length of the string data being pointed at.  See [Find the size of a string pointed by a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551017/)

On the Delphi side:

- you are not allocating any memory for the dynamic array before taking a pointer to it's payload.
- your C++ code is implemented as a non-static class method, but your Delphi code is not accounting for the method's implicit `this` parameter (ie the `Self` parameter in Delphi class methods). It needs an object to call the method on.

Due to compiler differences, it is not a good idea to expose direct access to C++ objects across the DLL boundary. You should re-implement the DLL function as a flat C-style function instead. You can still use your `exportClass`, but internally to the DLL only, and will have to abstract access to it on the Delphi side.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
// export this
void* __stdcall getExportClassObj()
{
    return new exportClass;
}

// export this
void __stdcall freeExportClassObj(void *obj)
{
    delete (exportClass*) obj;
}

// export this
void __stdcall getDataReference(void *obj, char* &data, int &bufferLength)
{
    ((exportClass*)obj)->getDataReference(data, bufferLength);
}

// do not export this
void __stdcall exportClass::getDataReference(char* &data, int &bufferLength)
{
    // char* charArray: is member of exportClass
    charArray = "Pass this Array of Char By Reference";
    data = charArray;
    bufferLength = strlen(charArray);
}
```

```pascal
type
  GetExportClassObjFunc = function: Pointer; stdcall;
  FreeExportClassObjProc = procedure(obj: Pointer); stdcall;
  GetDataReferenceProc = procedure(obj: Pointer; var data: PAnsiChar; var bufferLength: Integer); stdcall;

getExportClassObj: GetExportClassObjFunc;
freeExportClassObj: FreeExportClassObjProc;
getDataReference: GetDataReferenceProc;

...

procedure callDllFunction();
var
  dynamicCharArray : array of AnsiChar;
  pData: PAnsiChar;
  length: Integer;
  Obj; pointer;
begin
  Obj := getExportClassObj();
  try
    getDataReference(Obj, pData, length);
    // use pData up to length chars as needed...
    SetLength(dynamicCharArray, length);
    Move(pData^, PAnsiChar(dynamicCharArray)^, length);
    ...
  finally
    freeDataReference(Obj);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should export a C function out of your DLL. And decide if you want the DLL function copy data into the passed buffer pointer or just give back the pointer to the data.

I build an example showing the DLL copying the data. I used a dynamic array as you've done in your question. The function inside DLL receive the pointer where to copy data (That is the Delphi dynamic array) and the length of the dynamic array. The function inside the DLL copy some data, up to the maximum length specified, and return the actual length.

I also used Ansi char to pass data as you seems to like this. Could could as well pass Unicode.

DLL source code:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall getDataReference(char* data, int* bufferLength)
{
    char charArray[] = "Pass this Array of Char By Reference";
    if ((data == NULL) || (bufferLength == NULL) || (*bufferLength <= 0))
        return;
    #pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
    strncpy(data, charArray, *bufferLength);
    *bufferLength = sizeof(charArray) / sizeof(charArray[0]);
}
```

And simple console mode Delphi application consuming that DLL:

```
program CallMyDll;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils;

type
    TGetDataReference = procedure (Data         : PAnsiChar;
                                   BufferLength : PInteger); stdcall;

var
    DllHandle        : THandle;
    GetDataReference : TGetDataReference;

procedure callDllFunction();
var
    DynamicCharArray : array of AnsiChar;
    DataLength       : Integer;
    S                : String;
begin
    DataLength := 1000;
    SetLength(DynamicCharArray, DataLength);
    GetDataReference(PAnsiChar(DynamicCharArray), @DataLength);
    SetLength(DynamicCharArray, DataLength);
    S := String(PAnsiChar(DynamicCharArray));
    WriteLn(S);
end;

begin
    try
        DllHandle := LoadLibrary('D:\FPiette\Cpp\MyDll\Debug\MyDll.dll');
        if DllHandle = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create('DLL not found');
        @GetDataReference := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, '_getDataReference@8');
        if @getDataReference = nil then
            raise Exception.Create('getDataReference not found');
        callDllFunction();
    except
        on E: Exception do
            Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
    WriteLn('Hit RETURN...');
    ReadLn;
end.
```