# Stack overflow issue: max capacity 2,077,072

Tags: c, stack-overflow

Essentially, I wrote a rather small random character generator, where the user can pick the length of the character string. The program can successfully create a string of length 2,077,072, but crashes with a stack overflow at one greater than that.

This number seems rather arbitrary, since log2(thatNumber) equals around 20.9. It's too small to exceed two mebibytes, and both 16-bit and 32-bit sizes are nowhere near. Why is it breaking here, of all places?

The program executes at least as far as the "Processing..." marker.

My code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char getChar(int, int, int);

//MAXIMUM PASSWORD LENGTH: 2,077,072
//2,077,073 gives stack overflow

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc != 5) {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments.\n Usage: PassGenII arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4\n");
        printf("arg1: Password length\narg2: Use lowercase characters? 0 or 1\narg3 Use uppercase characters? 0 or 1\narg4: Use numeric characters? 0 or 1\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        int passLength;
        int lower;
        int upper;
        int numeric;

        passLength = atoi(argv[1]);
        lower = atoi(argv[2]);
        upper = atoi(argv[3]);
        numeric = atoi(argv[4]);

        printf("\nPassword length: %d\n", passLength);
        printf("lowercase: %d\n", lower);
        printf("uppercase: %d\n", upper);
        printf("numerals: %d\n", numeric);
        printf("\nProcessing...");
        char pass[passLength];

        srand(time(NULL));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < passLength; i++) {
            pass[i] = getChar(lower, upper, numeric);
        }


        FILE *fp = fopen("C:/PassGen/password.txt", "w");
        for(i = 0; i < passLength; i++) {
            putc(pass[i], fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);

        printf("\n\nSuccessful! The password is in a text file\nin C:/PassGen/\n");

        return 0;
    }
}

char getChar(int lower, int upper, int numeric) {
    int rand1;
    int fail;
    char passChar;

    do {
        fail = 0;
        rand1 = rand() % 3;

        switch(rand1) {
            case 0:
                if(lower) {
                    passChar = rand() % 26 + 97;
                } else {
                    fail = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(upper) {
                    passChar = rand() % 26 + 65;
                } else {
                    fail = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(numeric) {
                    passChar = rand() % 10 + 48;
                } else {
                    fail = 1;
                }
                break;
        }
    } while(fail);

    return passChar;
}
```

Comment: You are creating an array of 2MB on the stack. That's a lot. Use dynamic allocation on the heap via `malloc` (and `free` later) for arbitrarily large arrays.

Comment: That solved it! I did it a little differently by removing the array altogether. I'll post the result in a bit

Comment: Yes, of course, if you are just generating a string of random characters that don't require information of previous characters, you can print the result right away. That's a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MOehm, I was able to modify the code to remove this limit. The new limit is now (2^32)/2 - 1, or 2,147,483,647. This makes much more sense, and is also much larger than before.

I could theoretically extend this limit even farther by using a larger variable type than `int` for the variable `passLength`, but I don't have any real reason to (and also I'll probably wind up having a `.txt` file taking up my entire hard drive if I did).

The modified bit of code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("C:/PassGen/password.txt", "w");

int i;
for(i = 0; i < passLength; i++) {
    putc(getChar(lower, upper, numeric), fp);
}

fclose(fp);
```

I essentially removed the array that was storing the characters altogether and instead chose to write the characters directly on to the `.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

`char pass[passLength];` This statement is creating problem if your passLength is huge number. It is never a good practice to declare huge array.

*Do not declare huge arrays to avoid buffer overflow*. Use `malloc` instead to allocate huge memory.

You may refer this [How many chars can be in a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351919/how-many-chars-can-be-in-a-char-array)