# Alternative methods of storing 1,000,000 character string in C programming

Tags: c, arrays

I have created a auto typer bot in C which simulate keys.

It first search for a paragraph according to user input and then simulate each character of that paragraph.

I have 3000 paragraph database and total number of character is more than 1,000,000.

So, please tell me, can i store all data in one character array?

My code is ---

```
char database[] = {"A string with more than 1,000,000 characters"};
char *start_position;
gets(s); // a small string given by user, this input is used to search which paragraph user want to simulate.
start_postion=strstr(database, s);
function_for_key_simulation();......
```

I have readed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351919/how-many-chars-can-be-in-a-char-array) that big array cause buffer overload.
**Please suggest me alternative methods to perform this task.**

Comment: It depends is the right answer. Depends on how you declared/allocated the array. But in any case, a 15 (or 16) byte char array is unlikely to be hitting any limits. Are you experiencing any specific problem with actual code or are you just asking theoretically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For string literals like `char *s = "abcd";` the standard requires the compiler should support a limit of at least 4095 chars, as defined in cstd 5.2.4.1:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:
>
> -- 4095 characters in a string literal (after concatenation)

That means you can safely define a string literal of 4095 chars. Make more chars beyond that will make the code not portable. Since some compiler may support more and some not.

For char arrays, like `char array[N];` it depends on the implementation and platform, it's normally not recommended to make huge arrays, if you need a big buffer to hold data, use dynamic allocated memory instead, which will give you exact feedback(return `NULL`) when it fails, other than a running time buffer overflow of other unexpected behavior.